# html2canvas downloading blurry image

Tags: javascript, html2canvas

Below is my HTML Code iam generating the image of this area using HTML2canvas

```html
<div id="modal1" class="modal bottom-sheet" >
  <div class="modal-content" style="background-color: green;">
    <p style="color: honeydew;">धन्यवाद <span  id="crazyoutput"></span>!</p>
          <h5 style="color: honeydew;"><i style="color:honeydew;" class=" material-icons">thumb_up</i>&nbsp;आप  आज  कार्यालय  में  उपस्थित  हो  सकते हैं.</h5>
<p style="color: honeydew;"> यह ई-पास <span style= "font-size: 1.64rem" id="dateoutput"></span> के लिए वैध है  </p> 
<p style="color: honeydew;">कृपया ई-पास डाउनलोड करें या ई-पास का स्क्रीन शॉट लेंऔर इसे  HMSI परिसर के प्रवेश द्वार पर सुरक्षा गार्ड को दिखाएं.</p>
<p style="color: honeydew;">आप के द्वारा डाउनलोड किया हुवा epass फ़ाईल/डाउनलोड फ़ोल्डर मे सेव हैं।</p>
<a style="float: right;background-color: darkslategrey;margin-left: 20px;"  href="https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbxRGU-vxYW9tpEPFmOfkV-_zyqo4fuGn0N7ku25ruqn5OWl0wlg/exec" target="_top" title="Daily Health Status Form" class=" modal-action modal-close waves-effect waves-red btn-small" id="button-to-hide1">Close</a>
          <a style="float: right;background-color:red" class="waves-effect waves-light btn-small" id="download-page-as-image" onclick="wholePage();">Download</a> 
 
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Using html2canvas able to download the image however content is showing Blurr in  [image]images

```js
function wholePage()
{
  html2canvas(document.querySelector("#modal1"), {
      onrendered: function(canvas)  
      {

        var img = canvas.toDataURL();
//        $("#result-image").attr('src', img).show();

        canvas.toBlob(function(blob) {
          saveAs(blob, "wholePage.png");    
        });

      }
  });

  return false;
}
</script>
```

Comment: Which part of the image is problematic? When viewed full-size, at 1366x240, it's no different to what I'd expect to see. That is to say - it's just standard anti-aliased text. If you screen-shot the current page and zoom-in, you'll find it closely resembles your own picture when zoomed. TLDR: Can't Reproduce your problem.

Comment: @enhzflep I have updated the HTML code  that I am converting into the image

Comment: You didn't answer my question. Which part of the image is a problem? Here, on the page viewed at 659x115.78 pixels, the image is being shrunk, so it does appear blurry (everywhere). But again, when your image is viewed at 100% of it's size (1366x240px) it is not blurry. I think you might be mistakenly thinking there's a problem with the output, when there's actually a small kink in your viewing procedure.

Comment: @enhzflep I Tried with size 1366x240 same issue 2nd line and the 4th line is not displaying properly

Comment: Oh right, I see. The problem is that some characters are rendered in the wrong position, correct? It seems likely that html2Canvas has issues with code like yours. (because of the character-set/language, not your code)

Comment: @enhzflep any solution..?

Comment: I didn't know it was a problem before now. I've no idea.